# React Context reset to default value

Tags: reactjs, authorization, react-context

I've tried using React Context for authorization on a website. I appears that whenever I refresh a page or change page, the context reset to default value. I am pretty new to react and web dev and I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3qyxo_UTR4&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6PRCpm9clX0WiBEMB70FWwd&index=3).
I'm using Typescrypt (and not js like the tutorial), React, axios and jwt for my project.

My back end works well, I can register and verify users.

This is the context I use :

```
//The value of the context (State and setState)
interface AuthContextValue{
    auth : {user: string ,pwd:string,roles:string,accessToken:string} | null;
    setAuth : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{user:string,pwd:string,roles:string,accessToken:string} | null>>;
}


const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextValue| undefined>(undefined);

interface AuthProviderProps {
    children : React.ReactNode;
}

//Provider to wrap around the parent components which children/distant children might need the user logged
export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({children}) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<{user:string,pwd:string,roles:string,accessToken:string} | null>(null);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

Here's the index where I wrap the context provider around my app

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
if (container) {
    const root = createRoot(container);
    root.render(
    <AuthProvider>
        <App/>
    </AuthProvider>
    
    );
} else {
    console.error('Failed to find the root element');
}
```

In my app I declare my routes, one of them is private :

```
                <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>
                <Route path="/private" element = {<PrivateTestPage/>}/>
                </Route>
```

Here's the RequireAuth :

```
function RequireAuth() {
    const auth = useAuth()?.auth;
    const location = useLocation();

    return (
        auth?.user
            ? <Outlet/>
            : <Navigate to="/login" state = {{from : location}} replace/>
 
    );
}

export default RequireAuth
```

and finally my login page :

```
const Login = (props:any) => {
    const setAuth = useAuth();

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

    const userRef = useRef(null);
    const errRef = useRef(null);

    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        setErrMsg('');
    }, [user, pwd])

    const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_URL,
                JSON.stringify({ loginId:user, password:pwd }),
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            );
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            const accessToken = response?.data?.accessToken;
            const roles = 'to implement' //response?.data?.roles;
            setAuth?.setAuth({ user, pwd, roles, accessToken });
            setUser('');
            setPwd('');
            navigate(from, {replace:true})
        } catch (err) {
            setErrMsg('Login Failed');
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
                <section>
                    <p ref={errRef} className={errMsg ? "errmsg" : "offscreen"} aria-live="assertive">{errMsg}</p>
                    <h1>Sign In</h1>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            id="username"
                            ref={userRef}
                            autoComplete="off"
                            onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                            value={user}
                            required
                        />

                        <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
                            value={pwd}
                            required
                        />
                        <button>Sign In</button>
                    </form>
                    <p>
                        Need an Account?<br />
                        <span className="line">
                            <a href={REGISTERPAGE_URL}>Sign Up</a>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </section>
        </>
    )
}

export default Login
```

In my home page, which display all the pages, I added a paragraph which let me see if there's something in the context `<p>{setAuth?.auth?.user}</p>`. When a user is auth at the login page, it goes back to the previous page it was browsing.

When I log in after browsing the home page, I can see that the context retrieved the user, but once I refresh the page, or change page and go back to home, the context is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the context value is meant to be reset after a refresh. The data is just not saved between sessions.

In this case, it would be better to use Redux and store the data in a local instance or cookies. It works wonder with the project.

Once again, I am not a pro, but if you're having a similar issue, check on Redux tutorials.